# Axios post requests are not working with Cordova/Capacitor in Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, axios, quasar-framework

It's really weird. I opened the dev server of my quasar app and everything works fine. `GET` requests also work, `POST` requests also work with my server (Hosted). I use the `Axios` package to do so. But when I build the app for android using Cordova, only `GET` requests work, when I test with my phone.

**To realize what's happening**: I used a `ref`. So when the app starts the data coming from the `GET` request is stored in a `ref`. So if the `ref` is `true` the data display in a `<p>` tag since there is no `console` option in the mobile app to check the returned data. It's working the data is being rendered from the `GET` request. I did the same thing to test the `POST` request, I made a `form`, and after `submit` the data is going to the server, and returning back data will be stored in a `ref` too. I have another `<p>` tag to render that data (which shows if the `ref` is true). However this is not happening, the `POST` request doesn't work at all I checked the PHPMyAdmin in the server too no data has been inserted.

I'm really struggling with this. Really appreciate it if somebody could help me with this. Why `POST` requests are not working with Cordova after build and only working with the web?. I have attached my code below. Thanks.

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <q-form @submit.prevent="registerUser" class="q-gutter-md">
      <q-input
        type="text"
        autofocus
        v-model="userForm.username"
        label="Username"
        color="info"
      />
    </q-form>
    <p v-if="userData">{{userData }}</p>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

const userData = ref();

const userForm = reactive({
 username: '',
});

const registerUser = async () => {
  await axios
    .post(`urlhere/register_app_user`, userForm)
    .then((response) => {
      userData.value = response.data;
    });
};
</script>
```

However, this `POST` request works on the web. But after I build it to android using Cordova it doesn't work. **I use Laravel for backend**

Comment: Have you set internet permission on Cordova?

Comment: Yes GET requests are working only POST requests are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the CSRF Token Issue with Laravel.

Simply go to,

app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

And In there add `'api/*'` inside the `protected $except` array like this,
**(This is a quick solution)**

```
protected $except = [
  'api/*'
];
```